# Subsetting with optional variable in R

Tags: r, subset

Is there a simple way to allow for optional variables in R? I'm looking for something like the `?` operator in regex. For example, say I have a data frame `x`. Let's say x has columns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. I would like to subset `x` such that I only retain `A`, `B` and `C`. So I use `x[,c("A", "B", "C")]`. But if one day I import a file into `x` and for some reason it does not have a column `C` and I run the code, I get an error because `R` cannot find the column `C`.

Is there a way to make each column optional? Something like `x[,c("A"?, "B"?, "C"?)]` so that if one of the columns is missing, R skips it and includes only `A` and `B` without throwing an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subset columns based on list of column names and bring the column before it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556353/subset-columns-based-on-list-of-column-names-and-bring-the-column-before-it)

Comment: I don't think the link you provided answers my question. In that question, the poster is looking for a specific column. In mine, I'm looking for columns that may not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just subset the vector of columns names to those that actually exist

```
x[, intersect(c("A", "B", "C"), names(x))]
```

Comment: Simple enough even for a dude like me. And it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Or `x[names(x) %in% c("A","B","C")]`, I guess.